# Oracle APEX version 3.2 tabindex not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

[image]I am trying to setup the tabindex for my elements (text fields, date fields, text area fields) and I can not figure out how to set them so the go straight down the page.  I am using the APEX developer to do this.  Setting the "HTML Form Element Attributes" on the field does not work when I put TabIndex="1".

Comment: Apex 3.2 is a rather old piece of software; honestly, I don't remember how it looked like back then, nor what "tabindex" would be. Could you, please, post a screenshot which shows what you mean? Or - of course - wait for someone else's opinion.

Comment: Picture has been added

Comment: Thank you, that would be Apex 3.2. Now, what is a "tabindex for your elements"? What does it mean that "tabindex goes straight down the page"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was some bad javascript. It took a while to find it.